# Decimal values are truncating with to_f

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-5

I have model called Item, where I am updating the unit_price (Data Type is Decimal) value, currently I am not putting any limit when storing the value, storing the value as it is. But now I can see this PG error **PG::NumericValueOutOfRange**, when the value exceeds the limit.

So I was just trying to limit the value and checking something in the console, Below is the data. (Here in the data I am not putting all the decimal values)

```
#<Item id: 167199, description: "192830139", category_id: 10327, unit_id: 5596, weight: 0.1e5, unit_price: 0.4083333333659917816764132553606237816656920077972709552126705653021442494641325536062378168e1

i = Item.find 167199

i.unit_price.to_f
=> 4.083333333659918
```

---

```
#<Item id: 167199, description: "192830139", category_id: 10327, unit_id: 5596, weight: 0.1e5, unit_price: 0.6511366980197836882065909262763993442019943880913510722934069011050182329156169820243980265070876781866034494363303661586489199452739290976143216266200531728395970406461889852558384421962422689303402903e-2

i.unit_price.to_f
=> 0.006511366980197837
```

Can I know what will be the reason the **to_f** automatically reduce the limit of the decimal? What will be best way to solve this issue, I was just thinking about some truncate with some limit.

Comment: Well, floats have limited precision. You can use [BigDecimal](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html) instead. Another common way to solve this is by storing monetary values as whole numbers using the smallest unit possible, e.g. $1.95 as `195` (cents).

Comment: BTW, why do you have such `unit_price` in the first place? Are you using floats outside your database? (you shouldn’t)

Comment: No, I am not using any to_f now in ruby level, currently storing whatever we are getting from the calculation.

Comment: Why do you need about a 100 decimal places?

Comment: There are tons of articles about why you should never use floats for monetary units or calculations. This question sounds like a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/284887) to me.

Comment: Hi @spickermann, this is a very big old app, so now going with the least decimal change will be a huge impact, yeah that is the correct solution. So now I am looking for a solution like truncate, just to avoid the issue. so is this truncate will do any kind of rounding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I know what will be the reason the to_f automatically reduce the limit of the decimal?

The reason is the `to_f` methods are used to convert objects to [`Float`s](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Float.html), which are [standard 64-bit double precision floating point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Range_of_floating-point_numbers). The precision of these numbers is limited, therefore the precision of the original object must be automatically reduced during the conversion process in order to make it fit in a [`Float`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Float.html). All extra precision is lost.

It looks like you are using  [the `BigDecimal` class](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html). [The `BigDecimal#to_f` method](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html#method-i-to_f) will convert the arbitrary precision floating point decimal object into a [`Float`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Float.html). Naturally, information will be lost during this conversion should the big decimal be more precise than what [`Float`s](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Float.html) allow. This conversion can actually overflow or underflow if limits are exceeded.

> I was just thinking about some truncate with some limit

[There is a `truncate` method](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html#method-i-truncate) if you'd like explicit control over the precision of the result. No rounding of any kind will occur, [there is a separate method for that](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.2/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html#method-i-round).

- `BigDecimal#truncate`

  Deletes the entire fractional part of the number, leaving only an integer.

  ```
  BigDecimal('3.14159').truncate #=> 3
  ```
- `BigDecimal#truncate(n)`

  Keeps `n` digits of precision, deletes the rest.

  ```
  BigDecimal('3.14159').truncate(3) #=> 3.141
  ```

Comment: Hi @Matheus, thanks for you suggestion, so whatever precision we are giving into the truncate, that will just give the values right?, that will not do any rounding right?

Comment: @Developer Correct. Truncation simply deletes all digits after the specified precision. No rounding of any kind will occur. There is a separate method for that.

Answer (score -1):

you can use ruby's built-in .truncate() method

for example:

```
floatNum = 1.222222222222222
truncatedNum = floatNum.truncate(3) #3 is the number of decimal places you want
puts floatNum #returns 1.222
```

[image]

another way is to use the .round() method

for example:

[image]

Comment: Right, that is correct, but what could be the reason this to_f automatically reduce the limit of the decimal?

Comment: if u notice, the data type is bigdecimal. it is used to store larger decimals than float. This works just as float and double in java. That is what i think. It might be wrong tho.